# Spark email templates and master layouts

Tags: .net, spark-view-engine

I'm using the spark view engine outside of MVC to create HTML emails.  I've pulled the common layout elements into a master (template) view (Application.spark) and referenced the master view from my *.spark files using `<use master="Application.spark">`.  However, the HTML in the master view doesn't show up in my emails.  Any idea how to do this?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark doesn't need MSMVC specifically to have master layouts and views work together.

But unless you specifically supply your own version of the `IDescriptorFilter`, the `DefaultDescriptorFilter` will be used, and *it* expects that the `Application.spark` file is located in a folder called `Shared` or `Layouts` under the main `Views` folder. If it's in one of those two, you don't even need to reference it from any of your `*.spark` files, it will be used conventionally because of its name and location.

That's about all I can say from the info you've given, but I guess it could be something else, and I'd have to see some code or an example to help more...

Hope that helps,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding by adding Application.spark as template to the `descriptor`:

```
descriptor.AddTemplate("Application.spark");
```

and used `${Content["view"]}` instead of `<use content="view"/>` in the template.

Let me know if you have any issues after trying it.

There is also a workitem at the CodePlex site:
http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/workitem/9035